# Can I add a new keyboard shortcut in mac with tab key in it?

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, tab-key

I'm using a software called Notational Velocity for taking notes on my mac. It's great, there's just one shortcut thing I'd like to fix: the software indents with tab key like any other text editor, but when I want to "unindent" (move text to the left) it doesn't work like it does in all other editors (with shift+tab).

I tried to change this from my system preferences but noted that when I try to assing a shortcut with tab key in it, it simply changes focus out of the field I'm typing in, like the tab key does. So, how can I add a new shortcut shift+tab in mac's system preferences? I tried to google it but found no answers. Thanks in advance for help!

With best regards,
Juho

Comment: NV does indent/unindent with `Cmd-]` / `Cmd-[` (look in the `Format` menu).

Comment: Yeah I know, I just wanted it to unindent with that specific command since I use it in various other applications and thus try it automatically when trying to unindent. Also, I have a Finnish keyboard that does not have the [-key so I had to change the shortcut anyway. It's now cmd-<, I'll probably settle for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only `Tab` key (with/without `Shift`) is probably too dangerous or interferes with focus control, so they don't support it.

I tried editing the `.plist` preferences files myself, but even though the menu shows the correct shortcut, its use does not perform the menu command, but changes focus.

[image: Shift Tab]

Your options now are to dig into NV source code, or live with indent/unindent using `Cmd-]` / `Cmd-[`.

Comment: Hmph, irritating. Understandable though, but seems silly considering that numerous other applications use exactly that shortcut. Thanks anyway.